Re-open a window in the exact state when it's dismissed
I want to re-open a window in the exact state when it's dismissed (in order to show an immersive space in between). But simply calling dismissWindow(id:) and openWindow(id:) creates a new instance of the window. There are two approaches I can think of but neither is perfect:

Save the state and pass that in as a value to openWindow. However, the window is my main feed page with a dynamic scroll view. It opens a whole bag of worms, such as reading and setting the scroll offset.
Hide/show the window by using something like WindowGroup { TabView {}.opacity(showWindow ? 1 : 0) }. But the system window bar and close button are still visible.


https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/restoring_your_app_s_state_with_swiftui

This is what I ended up doing:
extension EnvironmentValues { var showMainWindow: Binding<Bool> {...} }

WindowGroup {
    TabView {
        FirstView()
          .tabItem {}
          .toolbar(showMainWindow ? .automatic : .hidden, for: .tabBar)
        
        SecondView()
          .tabItem {}
          .toolbar(showMainWindow ? .automatic : .hidden, for: .tabBar)
    }
    .opacity(showMainWindow ? 1 : 0)
    .persistentSystemOverlays(showMainWindow ? .visible : .hidden)
}
.environment(\.showMainWindow, $showMainWindow)

